# IN Query for count very slow with loading of page, looking for another solution

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have created the following Query:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(sire_id) as c, sire_id FROM dog WHERE sire_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY sire_id ORDER BY c desc LIMIT 150 "; 
$result = mysql_query($query) ;

$i=0;

while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $sireQuery = "SELECT name, id, sire_id, dam_id, yearofbirth FROM dog WHERE id = " . $line["sire_id"];
  $sireResult = mysql_query($sireQuery) ;
  $sireLine = mysql_fetch_array($sireResult);
  $sr = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM dog WHERE id = " . $sireLine["sire_id"]);  
  $sl = mysql_fetch_array($sr);     
  $dr = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM dog WHERE id = " . $sireLine["dam_id"]);
  $dl = mysql_fetch_array($dr);
  $queryMS = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT dam_id) FROM dog WHERE sire_id = " . $line["sire_id"];
  $resultMS = mysql_query($queryMS);    
  $totalMS = mysql_result($resultMS,0);

  $i++;
```

And now trying to get more info by adding the following

```
$queryoffS = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM dog WHERE sire_id IN (SELECT id FROM dog WHERE sire_id = " .$line[sire_id]. ")";
$resultoffS = mysql_query($queryoffS);  
$totaloffS = mysql_result($resultoffS,0);
$queryoffD = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM dog WHERE dam_id IN (SELECT id FROM dog WHERE sire_id = " .$line[sire_id]. ")";
$resultoffD = mysql_query($queryoffD);  
$totaloffD = mysql_result($resultoffD,0);
$totaloffspring = $totaloffS += $totaloffD;
```

But with adding that extra to my query the page loads really slow.
I wonder if there is a better way of writing this query so that it loads fast?

Comment: instead of running so many queries why dont you use join (single query)

Answer (score 0):

Revised query that I think will give you the counts you want with a single query.

```
SELECT dog.name, dog.id, dog.sire_id, dog.dam_id, dog.yearofbirth, parent_sire.name, parent_dam.name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT child.id) AS NumberOfChildren,
    COUNT(DISTINCT grandchild.id) AS NumberOfGrandChildren
FROM dog
LEFT OUTER JOIN dog AS parent_sire
ON dog.sire_id = parent_sire.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dog AS parent_dam
ON dog.dam_id = parent_dam.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, sire_id AS parent_id
    FROM dog
    UNION
    SELECT id, dam_id AS parent_id
    FROM dog
) AS child
ON dog.id = child.parent_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, sire_id AS parent_id
    FROM dog
    UNION
    SELECT id, dam_id AS parent_id
    FROM dog
)  AS grandchild
ON child.id = grandchild.parent_id
GROUP BY dog.name, dog.id, dog.sire_id, dog.dam_id, dog.yearofbirth, parent_sire.name, parent_dam.name
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, I am not an expert in PHP, that is why I mostly use separate queries. 

The database is a pedigree database. So what I am trying to get is the amount of offspring of a dog
Than from that dog I want to name his name and parents sire_id/dam_id is also id
So I basically go up a generation and down a generations.

Comment: Sorry hit enter... The last query I tried to write is 2d generation down how many offspring. So it has to select the id from the dogs which had him as sire_id than check if they appear as either sire_id or dam_id and count that amount of appearances.

Comment: I have amended my answer to give a query that I think will give you the results you want. A single query should be a lot faster than doing multiple queries in a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the help! it works and much faster now! :)